# How do I change bitmapdata in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm building a spritesheet class.  Hopefully this will be low hanging fruit to someone, but I'm stumped.

I have a spritesheet (.png) that I've loaded at runtime and placed a section of it on the stage using this code from within the Spritesheet class .as file **ouside** of the constructor method:

```
    private function onLoad(e:Event):void
{
    var loaderBmp:Bitmap = Bitmap(_loader.content);
    _bmpData.copyPixels(loaderBmp.bitmapData, new Rectangle(0,0,80,80),new Point(0,0));
}
```

That works fine.  I get my slice of the .png file displaying nicely.  In my case, the spritesheet is meant for animating a character, so I need to update the `BitmapData` and I'm not having any luck.  Here is what I'm trying this within my `Main` class in a function I use to alter the frame of the animation depending on the state of the character:

```
c._thisSpriteSheet._loader.content.bitmapData.copyPixels(loaderBmp.bitmapData, new Rectangle(0,20,50,30),new Point(0,0));
```

`loaderBmp` is a variable who's value is `var loaderBmp: Bitmap = Bitmap(_spriteSheet._loader.content);`

`c` is a reference to the `Runner` object that is the character.

`_spriteSheet` is a property of the `Runner` class of type `Spritesheet`.

`_loader` is a property of the `c._spriteSheet` and is the `Loader` object used when the spritesheet was instantiated.

It doesn't throw an error, but it also doesn't replace the original bitmapData object with the new one.  I thought maybe this meant that I need to create a new BitmapData object and use that in the `copyPixels` method, but that returned the same results (nothing).  When I step through the code in debug mode, everything looks like it is working, but my display object does not update with the new bitmapData.  What am I tripping on?

Answer (score 1):

What I was doing wrong was that I was trying to access the `BitmapData` object via the `Loader` that originally loaded it.  Then it dawned on me that I could simply reference the BitmapData directly via that property of the SpriteSheet class I had made.  I think this will be pretty confusing for someone else to follow.  If a moderator sees this and thinks it's junk, I don't mind it getting erased, but thought I'd keep it up anyway.  The new code looked like this:

```
c._thisSpriteSheet._bmpDSheet.copyPixels(loaderBmp.bitmapData, new Rectangle(0,20,50,30),new Point(0,0));
```

and `_bmpDSheet` is the bitmapdata property of the class.

Comment: Yep, if something is to be referred often, use a property and fill it with data. Note though, when you'll have a lot of similar objects with the same sprite sheet, you'll git a preformance issue with `copyPixels()`, you'll have to slice your `loaderBmp.bitmapData` first, store the set of `BitmapData` objects then change your `c._thisSpriteSheet._bmpDSheet` pointing to another member of that set instead of running `copyPixels()`.